# Is there an Australian magic school in the Potterverse?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

Is there a school of magic in Australia?

Answer (score 3):

## None are mentioned in canon yet, but JKR has hinted one exists.

There’s nothing confirming what wizarding school, if any, Australian wizards would typically attend. They certainly exist, as Australia has its own Quidditch League, and their magical community is mentioned as well. No school is named or specified as being the one they’d usually go to, though.

> “The Thundelarra Thunderers and the Woollongong Warriors have dominated the Australian League for the best part of a century. Their enmity is legendary among the Australian magical community, so much so that a popular response to an unlikely claim or boast is ‘Yeah, and I think I’ll volunteer to ref the next Thunderer-Warrior game’.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

However, JKR was asked about where Australian wizards would go to school on Twitter, and she responded to the question with “that information would be revealed in due course”.

[image]

This may mean that the Australian wizarding school will be mentioned at some point in the future. JKR has also said in her Pottermore writing on wizarding schools that there are eleven reputable and prestigious wizarding schools, and there aren’t eleven schools named yet.

> There are eleven long-established and prestigious wizarding schools worldwide, all of which are registered with the International Confederation of Wizards. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Wizarding Schools (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools)*</sup></sub>

This implies that it’s likely that one of the currently unnamed schools is the Australian wizarding school. Further implying that it’s yet to be revealed is that on January 29th, 2016, one day before JKR’s tweet about it, Evanna Lynch (who plays Luna Lovegood) hinted at there being a wizarding school located in Australia, before going on to reveal the names of and further information on four other wizarding schools written about by JKR on Pottermore - Castelobruxo in Brazil, Mahoutokoro in Japan, Uagadou in Africa, and  Ilvermorny in North America.

> What if I told you that there are wizarding schools in Africa, Brazil, Australia, Russia, and other secret locations? So this evening, for the very first time, I have the pleasure of reading to you brand new details about some of these wizarding schools. 
> <sub><sup>*[- A Celebration of Harry Potter (January 29th, 2016)](https://youtu.be/CGxHkys3ks4)*</sup></sub> on

JKR’s writings on these four schools were released on Pottermore right after this reveal by Evanna Lynch, so there was likely some level of planning and coordination with official sources behind the information she gave at the panel. As this vague mention of an Australian wizarding school came right before four other wizarding schools confirmed by JKR, and one day before JKR’s tweet implying one would be revealed, it seems likely that there’s a wizarding school in Australia that the name of and details about haven’t been mentioned as of yet but will be revealed at some point.

Comment: There can be wizards in Australia and a quidditch league even if there's no school. Rowling has said that a lot of countries without a school have extensive homeschooling or correspondence courses.

Comment: @Jetpack Agreed - that’s why I didn’t use the existence of Australian wizards as proof an Australian wizarding school might exist. I only mentioned that as proof that there are Australian wizards - my evidence for a possible Australian wizarding school is that JKR has implied one will be revealed.

Answer (score 2):

## Evanna Lynch revealed one in the HP celebration of 2016.

> What if I told you that there are Wizarding Schools in Africa, Brazil, Australia, Russia, and other secret locations? So this evening, for the very first time, I have the pleasure of reading to you brand new details about some of these Wizarding Schools.
> <sub><sup>*- [Evanna Lynch - HP Celebration 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SzgNaIV3_4)*</sup></sub>

This might have been an error on the part of whoever wrote her speech.
For reference i will put the video here: